# Controlling the Admin panel for page templates

Tags: page-template

I want to maintain a specific layout for each page type, rather than embedding HTML into the page itself. I know there has to be a better way, For example I would like to:

- on the contact page create a style for each person
- on the about page i would like to keep the content formatted

I know how to make a page-template.php but there has to be something i am missing I would think that in the admin panel there would be fields for each area.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

> I would think that in the admin panel there would be fields for each area.

I don't get this part, could you elaborate?.

Overall this sounds like a [custom page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) to me. You can create templaets in advance, but assign them to pages via admin rather than hardcode slig/id match in template name.

Comment: Well Advanced Custom fields seems to do what I am looking for. but a from scratch solution would give me more control.